# What moveset should my nidoking have?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-black-white

I have a nidoking (in my black version) with its hidden ability, sheer force. It has a high attack, and a somewhat low special attack (despite being bred with perfect special attack IVs), and I was wanting some good physical attacks for him that can take advantage of sheer force and his life orb. His current moves are: thunderbolt, earth power, sludge bomb, and flamethrower. I also have access to move tutors in black 2.

Comment: Sheer force gives more power to attacks, at the cost of a secondary effect (meaning earthquake doesn't gain the extra damage, but dart power, having the chance of lowering the targets special defense, does gain extra damage).

Comment: Pretty much the only physical moves he can learn that benefit from Sheer Force are the elemental Punches (which are still worse than the Special alternatives even after the Attack buff) and Bulldoze (which is still weaker than Earthquake even after the Sheer Force boost). You're better off building him Special (maybe mixed). Physical Nidoking is better off with outright strong attacks and Poison Point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I'd recommend keeping that moveset. All four moves have added effects, boosting their power due to Sheer Force. Then, the Life Orb boosts their power even further, with the ability negating the HP loss. If I were you, I would keep the move set as is.

If you really want to go for power, try replacing Thunderbolt with Thunder, Sludge Bomb with Sludge Wave (maybe, if you're okay with hitting allies in Double and Triple Battles), Flamethrower with Fire Blast, and leaving Earth Power as is.